# Invalid Certificate, form data and HTTP Header data with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, http-headers, alamofire

I want to use Alamofire for network requests. Server has invalid certificates and I have header values and form data to send. Now I've tried many SO questions but no luck so far. All I got is that I need to setup the Manager object properly. 
So allow invalid certs I did this:

```
let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = ["abc.com:8080/services/v2/xyz": .DisableEvaluation]
let manager = Manager(serverTrustPolicyManager:ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies))
```

Then to use Headers I did this:

```
var defaultHeaders = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders ?? [:]
    defaultHeaders["X-Auth-Module"] = "true"
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = defaultHeaders
    let manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
```

To merge the above 2 managers I did this:

```
let serverTrustPolicyManager:ServerTrustPolicyManager = ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
let manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration, delegate: Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.delegate, serverTrustPolicyManager: serverTrustPolicyManager)
```

Problem is with 'delegate', I'm unable to find the proper delegate to provide here. Or if there's any other simple way please suggest. Novice Swift dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to this problem:

```
    //set default headers
    var defaultHeaders = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders ?? [:]
    //I required this key    
    defaultHeaders["X-Auth-Module"] = "1"
        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = defaultHeaders

    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
        "10.10.10.1:8080": .DisableEvaluation
    ]

    manager = Alamofire.Manager(
        configuration: configuration,
        serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies))


    // Handling challange
    manager!.delegate.sessionDidReceiveChallenge = { session, challenge in
        var disposition: NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition = .PerformDefaultHandling
        var credential: NSURLCredential?

        if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust {
            disposition = NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential
            credential = NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
        } else {
            if challenge.previousFailureCount > 0 {
                disposition = .CancelAuthenticationChallenge
            } else {
                credential = self.manager!.session.configuration.URLCredentialStorage?.defaultCredentialForProtectionSpace(challenge.protectionSpace)

                if credential != nil {
                    disposition = .UseCredential
                }
            }
        }

        return (disposition, credential)
    }
```

Now after the manager is ready just use the **manager** object to create requests.

```
manager!.request(.POST, (req?.url())!, parameters: req?.headerParams(), encoding: .URL, headers:nil)
            .response(completionHandler: { req, res, data, error in
                print("req:\(req), res:\(res),data:\(data),error:\(error)")
            })
```